# Floss Foss to become Floss?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

As in many questions, [floss](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floss) and [foss](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foss) were deemed to be similar, if not the same (the difference being technical).

Should we make these tags synonyms of each other?

Comment: Even if someone has a question specifically about one or the other, I expect people following either tag will want to see it, so a synonym sounds good.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's make [foss](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foss) become [floss](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floss)!

Comment: OK, I have sufficient rights to create a synonym, but I still need 5 votes in that tag, so I couldn't create the synonym. As I see it, you will be the first who can create the synonym.

Answer (score -3):

This is partially to raise some concerns, partially to provide the alternative point of view to vote on.

FOSS and FLOSS, while very similar terms, do have some differences in clarity and implications. There may be some cases (rare, I know) where one tag is required and not the other. Thus, we should let these tags live as they are.

Comment: These are valid concerns. Thank you. :)

Comment: Please give an example of a question that would warrant one tag and not the other. This is the private beta, so if there's no such question, now is an ideal time to ask one! And please explain the difference in meaning between these two tags.

Comment: @Gilles the recent question about the difference between FOSS and FLOSS is one... In fact, there's a good explanation of the differences there too :)

Comment: @Gilles [Here's the link.](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/262/what-is-the-difference-between-foss-and-floss)

Comment: @HDE226868 Thanks. The answers explain how the terms are synonyms. (I was wondering who was nitpicknig so much as to make a difference in meaning between these terms.) So obviously the tags should be synonyms!